# Increase MaxJavaStackTraceDepth for Android DDMS

Tags: android, stack-overflow, dalvik

I've encountered a StackOverFlowError that is very hard to debug, and due to the limited depth of the stack trace, I am unable to find the root of the problem.

Is it somehow possible to increase the StackTraceDepth as with -XX:MaxJavaStackTraceDepth=1000000 for Android?

I'm not sure if it's interesting but here is the current stacktrace:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
        at android.support.v4.content.ModernAsyncTask$3.done(ModernAsyncTask.java:137)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
 Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
        at org.nfunk.jep.ASTFunNode.jjtAccept(Unknown Source)
        at org.nfunk.jep.SimpleNode.childrenAccept(Unknown Source)
        at org.nfunk.jep.EvaluatorVisitor.visit(Unknown Source)
        at org.nfunk.jep.ASTFunNode.jjtAccept(Unknown Source)
        at org.nfunk.jep.SimpleNode.childrenAccept(Unknown Source)
        at org.nfunk.jep.EvaluatorVisitor.visit(Unknown Source)
        at org.nfunk.jep.ASTFunNode.jjtAccept(Unknown Source)
        at org.nfunk.jep.SimpleNode.childrenAccept(Unknown Source)
        at org.nfunk.jep.EvaluatorVisitor.visit(Unknown Source)
        at org.nfunk.jep.ASTFunNode.jjtAccept(Unknown Source)
        at org.nfunk.jep.SimpleNode.childrenAccept(Unknown Source)
        at org.nfunk.jep.EvaluatorVisitor.visit(Unknown Source)
        at org.nfunk.jep.ASTFunNode.jjtAccept(Unknown Source)
        at org.nfunk.jep.SimpleNode.childrenAccept(Unknown Source)
        at org.nfunk.jep.EvaluatorVisitor.visit(Unknown Source)
        at org.nfunk.jep.ASTFunNode.jjtAccept(Unknown Source)
        at org.nfunk.jep.SimpleNode.childrenAccept(Unknown Source)
        at org.nfunk.jep.EvaluatorVisitor.visit(Unknown Source)
        at org.nfunk.jep.ASTFunNode.jjtAccept(Unknown Source)
        at org.nfunk.jep.SimpleNode.childrenAccept(Unknown Source)
        at org.nfunk.jep.EvaluatorVisitor.visit(Unknown Source)
        at org.nfunk.jep.ASTFunNode.jjtAccept(Unknown Source)
        at org.nfunk.jep.SimpleNode.childrenAccept(Unknown Source)
        at org.nfunk.jep.EvaluatorVisitor.visit(Unknown Source)
        at org.nfunk.jep.ASTFunNode.jjtAccept(Unknown Source)
        at org.nfunk.jep.SimpleNode.childrenAccept(Unknown Source)
        at org.nfunk.jep.EvaluatorVisitor.visit(Unknown Source)
        at org.nfunk.jep.ASTFunNode.jjtAccept(Unknown Source)
        at org.nfunk.jep.SimpleNode.childrenAccept(Unknown Source)
        at org.nfunk.jep.EvaluatorVisitor.visit(Unknown Source)
        at org.nfunk.jep.ASTFunNode.jjtAccept(Unknown Source)
        at org.nfunk.jep.SimpleNode.childrenAccept(Unknown Source)
        at org.nfunk.jep.EvaluatorVisitor.visit(Unknown Source)
        at org.nfunk.jep.ASTFunNode.jjtAccept(Unknown Source)
        at org.nfunk.jep.SimpleNode.childrenAccept(Unknown Source)
        at org.nfunk.jep.EvaluatorVisitor.visit(Unknown Source)
        at org.nfunk.jep.ASTFunNode.jjtAccept(Unknown Source)
        at org.nfunk.jep.SimpleNode.childrenAccept(Unknown Source)
        at org.nfunk.jep.EvaluatorVisitor.visit(Unknown Source)
        at org.nfunk.jep.ASTFunNode.jjtAccept(Unknown Source)
        at org.nfunk.jep.SimpleNode.childrenAccept(Unknown Source)
        at org.nfunk.jep.EvaluatorVisitor.visit(Unknown Source)
        at org.nfunk.jep.ASTFunNode.jjtAccept(Unknown Source)
        at org.nfunk.jep.SimpleNode.childrenAccept(Unknown Source)
        at org.nfunk.jep.EvaluatorVisitor.visit(Unknown Source)
        at org.nfunk.jep.ASTFunNode.jjtAccept(Unknown Source)
        at org.nfunk.jep.SimpleNode.childrenAccept(Unknown Source)
        at org.nfunk.jep.EvaluatorVisitor.visit(Unknown Source)
        at org.nfunk.jep.ASTFunNode.jjtAccept(Unknown Source)
        at org.nfunk.jep.SimpleNode.childrenAccept(Unknown Source)
        at org.nfunk.jep.EvaluatorVisitor.visit(Unknown Source)
        at org.nfunk.jep.ASTFunNode.jjtAccept(Unknown Source)
        at org.nfunk.jep.SimpleNode.childrenAccept(Unknown Source)
        at org.nfunk.jep.EvaluatorVisitor.visit(Unknown Source)
        at org.nfunk.jep.ASTFunNode.jjtAccept(Unknown Source)
        at org.nfunk.jep.SimpleNode.childrenAccept(Unknown Source)
        at org.nfunk.jep.EvaluatorVisitor.visit(Unknown Source)
        at org.nfunk.jep.ASTFunNode.jjtAccept(Unknown Source)
        at org.nfunk.jep.SimpleNode.chi
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output is being cut off because of a limitation in the logging system, not the stack depth.  The easiest thing to do would be to reduce the stack depth on the device, so that it fails sooner and the stack trace fits in a 4K log message.

If you create the thread yourself, you can configure the stack size in the Thread constructor.  It looks like this may be created by a thread pool, so you'd need to provide a ThreadFactory that used the [appropriate constructor](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html#Thread(java.lang.ThreadGroup,%20java.lang.Runnable,%20java.lang.String,%20long)).

At one point I wrote a patch for android.util.Log that detected the situation and stripped out the middle section of the trace, leaving you with the start and end, but I never made it production-ready.

Comment: I was able to solve it by isolating where it happened and by catching the StackOverflowError and printing the root cause. After looking through the jep code I realized memory usage grew exponentially, so I just switched to another library (JEXL), and Bob's your uncle.